# Object-oriented programming: Association 

Tags: c#, oop, uml

Well there is concept Association in UML So I want to implement it using C#.

/* 
In object-oriented programming, association defines a relationship between classes of objects which allows one object instance to cause another to perform an action on its behalf. This relationship is structural, because it specifies that objects of one kind are connected to objects of another */

Can you please show me how do we code Association relation between objects.

Thankyou

Comment: Take the "Master Object Oriented Design" course on www.eliminatecodefear.com - In my opinion, it's one of the best resources online for learning practical object oriented design and development with OOP HW assignments which makes it stand out. (HW is very important otherwise, you shouldn't even bother)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `StackOverFlowUser` class is associated with `StackOverFlowQuestion` class

  - `StackOverFlowUser` makes `StackOverFlowQuestion`

```
class StackOverFlowUser
{
    public StackOverFlowQuestion PostQuestion(string title, string msg)
    {
        //some logic
        
        return new StackOverFlowQuestion(title, msg);
    }
}

class StackOverFlowQuestion
{
    public StackOverFlowQuestion(string title, string msg)
    {
        //more logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. You get an up vote for making me laugh... but you are missing a closing brace in there somewhere.

Comment: This is not an example of the implementation of an association. There is no structural relationship between user and question, but merely a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

AirConditioner Class is associated with RemoteControl Class in a way that RemoteControl Class becomes a property of the AirConditioner Class. So we can say, AirConditioner Class has a property named RemoteControl but it also is a complete Class itself.

```
class AirConditioner
{
    //private members 
    private bool _airConditionerRunning;
    private RemoteControl _myRemote;

    //public method to access the remote
    public RemoteControl returnMyRemote()
    {
        return _myRemote;
    }

    //Rest of properties and methods etc
}

class RemoteControl
{
   //methods and peroperties of remoteControl Class
}
```